# JQuery Searching for elements using dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make it if you pick something in dropdown list except Condition, it will search all elements for that and show them.

my jquery:

```
$('#searchbtn').click(function(){
  var e = document.getElementById("condition");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  $('.item').each(function(){
    var itemcondition = $('.condition').html();
    if (itemcondition === strUser.toLowerCase()){
      $(this).show();
    }
    if (itemcondition !== strUser.toLowerCase()){
      $(this).hide();
     }
  });

})
```

my html:

```
<select id="condition">
    <option>Condition</option>
    <option value="factory new">Factory New</option>
    <option value="minimal wear">Minimal Wear</option>
    <option value="field tested">Field Tested</option>
    <option value="well worn">Well Worn</option>
    <option value="battle scarred">Battle Scarred</option>
 </select>
```

this is how element looks like:

```
<div class="item" data-keywords="m4a4 howl">
  <div class="name">M4A4 Howl</div>
  <div class="condition">Factory New</div>
  <div class="price">800 000 coins</div>
  <button>Buy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And the question is? What isn't working here, and what would the `.item` elements look like etc?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Did you mean you want to show `.item` element corresponding the dropdown list you selected ?

Comment: Yes and hide the others, i did figure it out, but it doesnt seem to work with my other function that filters elements by keyword. this is my entire code: http://codepen.io/killerek/pen/EgVZak

Comment: Okay I got it, it's pretty easy. I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can fix it.
Your html attribute and javascript code should be changed. You should give option value with ID/slug of condition of your products -- it shouldn't have space as we will manage this data easier in the next step.

```
<select id="condition">
    <option>Condition</option>
    <option value="factory-new">Factory New</option>
    <option value="minimal-wear">Minimal Wear</option>
    <option value="field-tested">Field Tested</option>
    <option value="well-worn">Well Worn</option>
    <option value="battle-scarred">Battle Scarred</option>
 </select>
```

and your products list should classes corresponding your selected option value like this.

```
<div class="item factory-new field-tested" data-keywords="m4a4 howl">
  <div class="name">M4A4 Howl</div>
  <div class="condition">Factory New</div>
  <div class="price">800 000 coins</div>
  <button>Buy</button>
</div>
```

And your javascript should be changed almost entirely. It's much easier to understand.

```
$('#searchbtn').click(function() {
    var $condition = $("#condition");
    var condition = $condition.val();
    $('.item').hide();
    $('.item.' + condition).show();
})
```

hope it helps.